# trap ignoring exit signal

Tags: bash, shell

I have a simple bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Zip data and upload it to a cloud storage provider

set -euo pipefail

# some config and funcs removed, only relevant are left.
file=foo
dest=bar
temp_dir=$(mktemp -d)

fail() {
    log "$1"
    exit 1
}

log() {
    echo "$(date) - $1"
    echo "$1" | systemd-cat -p notice -t cloud_archive
}

put_archive() {
    # Put archives into storage.
    # This is where we fail
    cp "${file}" "${dest}" || fail "Uploading failed"
}

cleanup() {
  # remove some temp files etc.
  # and send message to stdout and journal
  log "Deleting temp dir ${temp_dir}."
  rm -r "${temp_dir}"
}

put_archive
trap cleanup EXIT
```

From my understanding this is the basic use case for a bash trap. The `cp` command fails with `$? != 0`, triggering the `fail` function, which in turn sends a log message to the journal and then `exit 1`. The `trap` should catch that signal and fire `cleanup`. That part is what does not work. The script just exits with log message "Uploading failed" and does not fire `cleanup`. I do not see the log output from that function and `temp_dir` still exists.

What I did:

- Remove `set -euo pipefail`
- Add `set -x` to verify executed commands, which did not result in anything useful
- There are no subshells which might interfere with the `trap`
- `trap` is not used within a function which could have been not yet defined when the script exits

I am having a hard time understanding what I am doing wrong. What am I not seeing here?

Comment: Just place `trap` directive line **before** running your `put_archive` function!! Otherwise, if your function `fail`, your `fail` function will **`exit`** your script without executing `trap` directive.

Comment: You need to swap the order of the last two lines. As it is, you haven't set the trap before the error occurs.

Comment: Thanks @F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub and Mark Setchell, your comments made it work. If you post it as an answer, I can mark it as solved.

Comment: What is the point in defining a trap as the last statement of a script? Once the script reaches the end, it exits anyway; you could equally well invoke there `cleanup` explicitly - it would have the same effect as your trap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just place `trap` directive line **before** running your `put_archive` function!!

Otherwise, if your function *`fail`*, your `fail` function will exit your script *before* executing trap directive.

```bash
fail() {
    log "$1"
    exit 1
}
put_archive() {
    something || || fail "some message"
}

trap cleanup EXIT

put_archive
```

But you could build another *exit* way:

```
fail() {
    log "$1"
    cleanup 1
}
log() {
    echo "$(date) - $1"
    echo "$1" | systemd-cat -p notice -t cloud_archive
}
cleanup() {
    log "Deleting temp dir ${temp_dir}."
    rm -r "${temp_dir}"
    exit ${1:-0}
}
put_archive() {
    cp "${file}" "${dest}" ||
        fail "Uploading failed"
}

put_archive
cleanup
```

Doing so, you don't need to use `trap` directive.